# How are user sessions handled in quarkus based keycloak versions

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

In older keycloak versions, to my understanding, a record is kept in the SSO_TOKEN table in the database when a user logs in with regards to the user session but in version 18.0.0 (the version I'm using that is based on quarkus) no record is persisted.

How does new versions of keycloak handle this? Is there a different table to persist this data? or does it uses a different mechanism altogether?

Comment: I would say sessions are in the cache, not in the DB.

Comment: @jan-garaj But clearing the cache doesn't logout the user. I cleared all caches from `Realm Settings > Cache`. Also, any idea what the usage of SSO_TOKEN table is?